# SteamUser()->GetSteamID() returning wrong ID

Tags: c++, steamworks-api

As part of a program I'm working on, I'd like to check which DLCs of a certain game the user that's currently logged into steam owns. However, I've hit an early roadblock as I can't get the correct ID.

```
SteamAPI_Init();
CSteamID sid
if(SteamUser())
    sid = SteamUser()->GetSteamID();
```

The ID that's returned is 317503778041363804. But the actual ID of the logged in account is 76561198112533289. If I manually hardcode my actual ID, then I can continue without issues. I'm pretty stumped here, I'm relying on being able to get the proper ID and don't know why this method would return something different. Unfortunately the documentation is rather sparse.

Comment: I understand that code is probably just an example for us, but I notice the `sid` value is only valid during the life of that if statement. If you're looking at the value in a debugger it may show the variable outside of its scope or something.

Comment: Yes, you're right about that, I've edited the code to get rid of that. However, that wasn't the issue. If I hardcode my ID I can continue and e.g. start an AuthSession, but when I do that with the ID returned, BeginAuthSession will issue an invalid ticket error.